# Simple tesseract script throwing error

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
im = Image.open("news.jpg")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng')

print(text)
```

So the code above throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                              
  File "C:\Users\test\Documents\Projects\TesseractTest\main.py", line 6, in <module>            
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang='eng')                                          
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string 
    config=config)                                                                              
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract    
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)                                    
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__                                   
    errread, errwrite)                                                                          
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in _execute_child                             
    startupinfo)                                                                                
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The news.jpg is present and I'm running this on windows 10.

Thanks, Ed.

Comment: The file is not acessible. Keep the news.jpg in the same folder in which your script resides.

Comment: It is in the same file.

Comment: Please provide the location of your news.jpg in your question including full path of it.

Comment: it's not a problem of .jpg.

Comment: How are you running Python? From the command prompt? Or some IDE?

Comment: The path is `C:\Users\test\Documents\Projects\TesseractTest` but so is the script's.

Comment: Running from command prompt.